# How do I search and remove text using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I need to search and remove this span `<span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">nclex_rn_qbank</span>` from the HTML below using XSLT. How would I do that?

My script is setup to only make this change on certain files, not all so I can't do a simple search and replace in all files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>n002001_ORG</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set">
            <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta"
                            data-value="n002001_ORG"></span>
                    </section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span property="ktp:interactionType" class="ktp-meta">single-select</span>
                        <span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">nursing</span>
                        <span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">nclex_rn</span>
                        <span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">nclex_rn_qbank</span>           
                    </section>
                </section>  
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
<xsl:template match="span[@property='atom:tag' and @class='ktp-meta' and normalize-space(.) = 'nclex_rn_qbank']"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It works on the sample section but isn't working on my full HTML. I added the complete HTML to my original post.

Comment: @mjwolff1, if the namespace in your original XML is causing the suggested code not to work then you can add `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` as an attribute of the `xsl:stylesheet` (or `xsl:transform`) root element of the complete stylesheet.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I have to apply ```<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$content-item-name = $input-qid">``` so it only removes the span on certain files. How can I add that code to the ```<xsl:template match="span[@property='atom:tag' and @class='ktp-meta' and normalize-space(.) = 'nclex_rn_qbank']"/>``` line?